# WPF. Catch last window click anywhere

Tags: wpf, window, click

Is there anyway that a class can catch the last click in the application? Something like

```
public class MyClickManagerClass
{
    public MyClickManagerClass()
    {
        // subscribe to a global click event
    }

    private void GlobalClickEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // do something with the click here
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you only care to capture mouse clicks anywhere in a given `Window`, simply subscribing to the `MouseDown` or `PreviewMouseDown` at the window level does the trick.

If you really want it to be global to the application (and not just to the window), you should subscribe to the `InputManager.PreProcessInput` or `InputManager.PostProcessInput` event and watch for mouse events:

```
public MyClickManagerClass()
{
  InputManager.Current.PreProcessInput += (sender, e) =>
  {
    if(e.StagingItem.Input is MouseButtonEventArgs)
      GlobalClickEventHandler(sender,
        (MouseButtonEventArgs)e.StagingItem.Input);
  }
}
```

Note that "sender" will always be the InputManager but you can map coordinates to other controls with `MouseEventArgs.GetPosition(visual)`.