# WPF Event Handler For All Events Everywhere

Tags: c#, wpf, events, event-handling, dispatcher

We're adding a security feature to an application that makes it "time out" in a given number of minutes, kicking the user out if they are inactive for that long. Making the timer and displaying it, etc. was all very easy as you might expect.

I then get to the part where any action on the application should reset the timer, and I can't seem to find a clean/simple way to hook into the "event pipeline" and respond to all user interaction by resetting the timer. I figured there would be somewhere/some way to do that, but so far my research has turned up nothing.

I was basically hoping for something along these lines:

```
Dispatcher.EventHandling += delegate (object e) 
{
  //assuming this were to come before the event went anywhere from its source
  ((RoutedEventArgs)e).Handled = false; 
  MyTimeSpan = TimeSpan.Zero; 
};
```

(I realize that this code doesn't check for the specific type of event, but it gets the point across)

**This is not the same as the question that it was marked as duplicate of - while the answer was applicable here, the question is totally different and did not show up in searches/etc. when trying to find the answer to this question.**

Comment: Not sure what you meant on user interaction. Is it all mouse / keyboard events including mouse moves that you want to catch?

Comment: In this case I think this might help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105607/wpf-catch-last-window-click-anywhere

Comment: That was *precisely* what I wanted - post it as an answer so I can give you credit!